# C# SOAP Client instantiate time is slow

Tags: c#

I have a web service I'm calling and upon investigation I see the creation of the client is taking about 0.5-1 second alone. This is using web reference .net 2.0.

```
SomeWS.SomeWSSoapClient client = new SomeWS.SomeWSSoapClient(); // takes 0.5-1 seconds
```

Is this normal? Is it fetching something from the service endpoint that I can stop?

I compared it to adding via a service reference and while the client takes a short time to instantiate (0.2 secs) the method call takes a lot longer and the overall time is longer.

What can I do to speed up the instantiate time? Which method should be quicker?

thanks a lot!
Ash

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have gotten an answer yet or not, but I believe it has something to do with the full scope of the web service, I have an application currently connected to another web service that takes 5-10 sec to instantiate because the WSDL is somewhere in the MB range. To work around this, I went through the work to send and receive the SOAP requests through raw XML and Web Client, sine I only use a fraction of what the WS offered.

If anyone else has a better idea, I'm all ears!

Comment: your answer should be added as a comment, as it does not solve the issue

Comment: I didn't resolve it yet. Surprised no one else has had similar issues.